# What are all the critical points of the function $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2) e^{y^2 - x^2}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I know that I must find the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, then set them equal to zero.

So:

$$f_x = 2xe^{y^2 - x^2} (1 - (x^2 + y^2))$$
$$f_y = 2ye^{y^2 - x^2} (1 + (x^2 + y^2))$$

I can't seem to figure out how I can find the critical points form here.

Comment: You just need to use { and } around, like this : "e^{ exponent }"

Answer (score 2):

The critical points are where partial derivatives are 0, right?

**Hint:**

So we have a product of numbers. A product which is equal to 0 is when *at least one* of the factors is 0. Also we can use that the exponential function is never $0$ for any input.

Answer (score 1):

If $a.b=0$ , then either $a =0$ or $b=0$ or $a=b=0$.

Now from $f_x=0$, we have $x=0$ or $x^2+y^2 =1$. 
From $f_y=0$, we have $y=0$ or $x^2+y^2 =-1$.

EDIT : 
critical points would be,  $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0, i)$

Comment: thanks for that, but how did you get (i,0)?

Comment: I agree with user. don't you mean $(0,i)$ ?

Comment: have you not flipped (x,y) to (y,x)?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.